# Instantiating a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iterable, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to instantiate a nested dictionary which contains another dictionaries as keys and each of these dictionaries contains another dictionaries. I know what keys and how many keys will be in nested and nested-nested dictionaries, but I don't know how many and what keys will be in the upper dictionary (which will be OrderedDict and keys will be integers but I don't know how many).

The upper dictionary contains integers as keys and dictionaries as values - each of these dictionaries has 3 `keys = 'forth','back'` and `'price'`.

`'forth'` and `'back'` has another dictionaries as their values. Each of these dicts (values) contains these keys

```
'arr_date','arr_place','dep_date','dep_place'.
```

So for example 'forth' dict is:

```
dict.fromkeys(['arr_date','arr_place','dep_date','dep_place'],None)
```

So the point is that I want to instantiate the dictionary with these keys but the problem is that upper dictionary can has variable integers. It can contains these keys `[1,2,3,4]` but also can contains `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`.

This is an example of instantiation of nested and nested-nested. So this would be a value of upper dictionary for each of it's keys  (I'm not sure if condition will work).

```
dict.fromkeys(['forth','back','price'], dict.fromkeys(['arr_date','arr_place','dep_date','dep_place'],None) if key in ['forth','back'] else None)
```

The whole thing is that I want to tell the code as much as possible default values and keys.

Any advices?

EDIT: The condition 6 lines above does not work so anybody could tell how to do that too.

EDIT II: So the dict should looks like:

```
 {1:{'forth':{'arr_date':'15-8-4','arr_place':'Atlanta','dep_date':'15-8-4','dep_place':'New York'},'back':{'arr_date...},'price':158},2:{....}}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what this dictionary might look like using literal dictionary syntax? I don't quite understand what you want to do.

Comment: I do not understand your question completely, but are you sure you want to have some dictionary as a key for another dictionary? This is impossible, since keys needs to be hashable objects, which dictionaries are not ...

Comment: If you really have dictionaries of dictionaries of dictionaries then keeping the various levels straight can seem complex. You can introduce functions to manage the complexity. Write a function `makesimpledict` that can make the innermost dicts (with whatever default values you want) then write another function `makemetadict` which uses the first function to create the values of and return the middle level dictionaries then at that stage making the top-level dict can be a simple dictionary comprehension using `makemetadict`

Comment: @BasSwinckels You are 100% correct about that. I suspect that the OP meant a dictionary whose *values* are dictionaries. If so, they should edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
def inner_dict(vals = []):
    my_vals = vals  + [None]*(4 - len(vals))
    my_keys = ['arr_date','arr_place','dep_date','dep_place']
    return dict(zip(my_keys,my_vals))

def middle_dict(fvals = [], bvals = [], price = None):
    d = {"forth": inner_dict(fvals),"back":inner_dict(bvals), 'price': price}
    return d
```

Typical use:

```
>>> middle_dict(['5-18-4', 'Atlanta','5-18-4','New York'],
        ['5-19-4', 'New York','5-19-4','Atlanta'], 134.05)
{'forth': {'arr_date': '5-18-4', 'dep_place': 'New York', 'dep_date': '5-18-4', 'arr_place': 'Atlanta'}, 'price': 134.05, 'back': {'arr_date': '5-19-4', 'dep_place': 'Atlanta', 'dep_date': '5-19-4', 'arr_place': 'New York'}}
>>> 
>>> d = {i:middle_dict() for i in range(1,4)}
>>> d
{1: {'forth': {'arr_date': None, 'dep_place': None, 'dep_date': None, 'arr_place': None}, 'price': 0.0, 'back': {'arr_date': None, 'dep_place': None, 'dep_date': None, 'arr_place': None}}, 2: {'forth': {'arr_date': None, 'dep_place': None, 'dep_date': None, 'arr_place': None}, 'price': 0.0, 'back': {'arr_date': None, 'dep_place': None, 'dep_date': None, 'arr_place': None}}, 3: {'forth': {'arr_date': None, 'dep_place': None, 'dep_date': None, 'arr_place': None}, 'price': 0.0, 'back': {'arr_date': None, 'dep_place': None, 'dep_date': None, 'arr_place': None}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should produce the empty ordered dict you're looking for assuming you want to instantiate with None values in your nested dicts:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d=OrderedDict()
for x in range(1,6):
    d[x]={key:dict.fromkeys(['arr_date','arr_place','dep_date','dep_place'],None) if key in ['forth','back'] else None for key in ['forth','back','price']}
```

Which gives the following dict:

```
In[42]: dict(d)
Out[42]: {1: {'price': None, 'forth': {'arr_date': None, 'dep_date': None, 'arr_place': None, 'dep_place': None}, 'back': {'arr_date': None, 'dep_date': None, 'arr_place': None, 'dep_place': None}}, 2: {'price': None, 'forth': {'arr_date': None, 'dep_date': None, 'arr_place': None, 'dep_place': None}, 'back': {'arr_date': None, 'dep_date': None, 'arr_place': None, 'dep_place': None}}, 3: {'price': None, 'forth': {'arr_date': None, 'dep_date': None, 'arr_place': None, 'dep_place': None}, 'back': {'arr_date': None, 'dep_date': None, 'arr_place': None, 'dep_place': None}}, 4: {'price': None, 'forth': {'arr_date': None, 'dep_date': None, 'arr_place': None, 'dep_place': None}, 'back': {'arr_date': None, 'dep_date': None, 'arr_place': None, 'dep_place': None}}, 5: {'price': None, 'forth': {'arr_date': None, 'dep_date': None, 'arr_place': None, 'dep_place': None}, 'back': {'arr_date': None, 'dep_date': None, 'arr_place': None, 'dep_place': None}}}
```